# Difference between "comment_form_default_fields" AND "comment_form_fields"

Tags: theme-development, comments, hooks

What is the difference between `comment_form_default_fields` and `comment_form_fields`?

Description in the official code reference seems to differ only by the word "default".

What's the difference in application? Which hook can I use to change the html output of fields for example? And what's the purpose of the other hook then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`comment_form_default_fields`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L2216) filter hook you can change *email*, *author* and *url* fields but cannot change *comment* field. And using [`comment_form_fields`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L2352) filter hook you can change all the 4 fields. You can use both filter hooks to change html.